# Как из Frame закрыть все модальные окна, и открыть главное окно?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопка в Frame

```
 private void btnExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Вы уверены что хотите выйти из учётной записи?", "Информация",

       MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
       MessageBoxImage.Question);

        foreach (Window window in App.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                if (window is TeacherStart)
                {
              
                    window.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    
                    AuthorizationWindow authorizationWindow = new AuthorizationWindow();
                    authorizationWindow.Show();
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }
```

Она работает при условии если, в проекте закрывалось 1 модальное окно.

А если допустим, мы делаем так.

Запускаем программу, на одном из Frame есть кнопка с этим кодом, он сработает.

И когда запускаем уже другое окно (не тоже самое), то в итоге текущие модальное окно не скрывается уже.

Как насильно закрыть МОДАЛЬНЫЕ ОКНА?? И открыть основное окно ?

Comment: А если этот код вызывать из окна (ну то есть кнопка находится не в Frame а в самом модальном окне, то это окно скрывается) А  как из Frame вызывать событии Окна ? (кнопки и т.д.)

Comment: `Есть кнопка в Frame` может все-таки на `Page` кнопка? Фрейм нужен для отображения страниц

Comment: @Pekor, Да , в Page